# In order to start photo prism I need to run the command "sudo docker-compose up -d"

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

everytime my server restarts I need to add the following command into terminal to get photoprism to work:

sudo docker-compose up -d

Any idea how to automate this process. Realize this might be a basic question but new to linux, containers etc...

Comment: Have a read here for some options https://linuxconfig.org/automating-raspberry-pi-how-to-autostart-programs

Comment: Thanks I have added the command at the bottom of the cron job "reboot sudo docker-compose up -d" but it is still failing to execute.

Comment: It should be `@reboot...`. Also, try the other methods. Also, check that if you do `sudo su` in your normal Terminal, that you can use `docker-compose` - it may not be on root's PATH. To check where `docker-compose` really lives from your regular Terminal, run `type docker-compose`.

Comment: Also, you surely need to change directory before running `docker-compose` for it to be able to find its files.